# Join / Replace data in CSV from another CSV

Tags: csv

I have 2 seperate CSV files, one with 'Products', the other with 'Users'.

**Products.csv**

```
Name | Owner | Price
Belt | 5121 | 14.25
Shoe | 3692 | 20.50
```

**Users.csv**

```
Name | User# | Phone_Number
Rick | 3692  | 8888675309
Sami | 5121  | 8888675309
```

I would like the resulting csv to simply replace the 'owner' field with the corresponding name from the other csv, like so:

**Updated_Products.csv**

```
Name | Owner | Price
Belt | Sami | 14.25
Shoe | Rick | 20.50
```

I'm using Windows, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Currently using CSVed program to attempt Joining / replacing the values, no luck however.

Comment: CSVed - Software? If you are asking "how to use software?" then it becomes off topic question for stackoverflow. And if you try to write some code to achieve this task and face some problem, we can help you. For that you will need to first try to write some code on your own.